# How to ensure exactly one service instance per docker swarm node

Tags: docker

I would like to deploy a docker swarm that harvests sensor data from multiple field machines.

Is it possible to ensure that **exactly one** container of a specific service is started on every worker node in a docker swarm?

I am looking for something which is more predictable than just scale the service to the same number of replicas as the number of docker nodes.

At the same note; I would like to avoid that the service is deployed to any manager node.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by using the Global mode for deployment and Host mode for exposing ports. In global mode the services deployed are based on placement constraints. So if you want to run Nginx service on 2 worker nodes you can do it by using the below docker-compose files.

```
version: '3.2'

networks:
  testnetwork:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true

services:
  nginx1:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    networks:
      testnetwork:
        aliases:
          - nginx1.test.com
    deploy:
      mode: global
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        max_attempts: 3
      placement:
        constraints: [node.hostname == worker1]
```

```
version: '3.2'

networks:
  testnetwork:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true

services:
  nginx2:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    networks:
      testnetwork:
        aliases:
          - nginx2.test.com
    deploy:
      mode: global
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        max_attempts: 3
      placement:
        constraints: [node.hostname == worker2]
```

You can see that the **placement.constraints** define the **hostname** of the node on which the service should be deployed, you can also used IPs.

The ports exposed are specific to the Host on which the node is deployed and do not conflict with the ports of other Hosts. If a service requires multiple ports to be exposed you can add in more in the Ports section. Make sure that the service Names and Aliases never conflict with each other.

Comment: There is also a new feature available called `max_replicas_per_node`: https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/1410